# How should I do to pop all or Specific Number viewsController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This code is to pop only one viewController.

How should I do to pop all or Specific Number viewsController?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW4) (to pop all) or popToViewController:animated: to pop to a specific view controller in the navigation stack.